# How to get particular value from the $request object in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, request

I have an API which is responsible for downloading the excel sheet , my request object contains some values based on the request object, I want to get the `user_ID` value please help me to achieve this.

**dd($request)**

```
^ App\Containers\Charge\UI\API\Requests\GetAllUsersRequest {#1638
  #transporter: "App\Containers\Charge\Data\Transporters\GetAlluserssTransporter"
  #access: array:2 [
    "permissions" => "list-payments"
    "roles" => ""
  ]
  #decode: array:2 [
    "id" => "user_id"
    "customer_id" => "cus"
  ]
  #urlParameters: array:1 [
    0 => "id"
  ]
  #map: []
  #account_id: 1313
  #merchant_id: 9809
  #user_id: 143
```

**Controller.php**

```
public function download(GetAllUsersRequest $request){
$request->user_id; //it's taking null
}
```

Comment: Can you add `GetAllUsersRequest` file?

Comment: Do `dd($request->all())` to see the variables the request has access to. `dd($request->validated())` to see what they look like after validation. And if you want access to the authenticated user, you can do `dd(auth()->user())` (or `Auth::user()`)

Comment: what is dd($request->all()) returning ? can you please show the output for that?

Comment: this is not something that extends from `Illuminate\Http\Request`; this is some custom class ... you would have to show the definition for this class

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a direct variable you can use:

```php
$user_ID = $request->input('user_ID');
```

-or-

```php
$user_ID = $request->user_ID;
```

Alternatively:

```php
$req = $request->all();
$user_ID = $req['user_ID'];

# Debugging:
dd($request->all());
```

Answer (score 1):

If your request has for instance an ID, name and email you can access each attribute by simply doing this:

```
$request->email

$request->ID 

$request->name
```

It works as Grant stated, but with this you save some brackets